# Success of the StackExchange engine the undoing of StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

Just noted @spolsky tweet "Stack Exchange of the day" http://ask.sqlservercentral.com clearly focusing on SQL server.

I also discovered http://uxexchange.com/ focusing on User Experience issues.

I suspect there may be more Stack Exchange based sites with a more tightly focused programming related subject area and more to come.  Which is great for those guys that own Stack Exchange.

However now if I have a SQL server question where do I ask? Stack Overflow or ask.sqlservercentral.com?  What happens if someone builds a CSharpExchange, JavaExchange etc?

Bottom line, is this proliferation going to dilute and ultimately undermine the benefit of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Usually stuff like Java.SE and C#.SE are closed on Area51, no danger of that happening.

Comment: I would argue that these things work themselves out, in the long run. There will surely be overlap, but who is the beneficiary of having more options? I think the end-user benefits.