# Are broken duplicate question links automatically cleaned up?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, broken-link

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27686/success-of-the-stackexchange-engine-the-undoing-of-stackoverflow) is marked as a duplicate of [this (now removed) question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25558/stack-exchange-is-splintering-off-portions-of-so-is-that-a-problem) but the *'Possible Duplicate'* link has not been removed by the [Broken Link AutoCleaner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47898/broken-link-in-linked-posts-section/79318#79318).

Does the AutoCleaner process not handle abandoned dupe links?  Or do now-dead dupe links just need to be hidden from non 10k users?

Side note: Should there be a '*Question you are trying to remove/delete is marked as the original of [this] duplicate question*' warning when removing/deleting questions?

**Edit #1** - As Kobobby has pointed out, it appears that the auto-cleanup is only for the 'Linked' section in the side bar.  So does this mean there is NO automated checking for abandonded duplicate question links in questions?  If so, that might need looking into.

Comment: As an aside: since February 2013, duplicate links are no longer inserted [into](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162061/has-the-automatic-linking-to-exact-duplicates-been-broken/166901#166901) the question text.

Answer (score 3):

[Quote from Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79318/136489):

> Linked questions are cleaned up every 30 days, and also any time anything in the question is edited; so just be patient and these deleted linked items will be removed over time.

[Linked Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/) != Links to questions in questions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the distinction.